# Question on Munkres topology's lemma 38.1.

Tags: general-topology

Lemma 38.1. Let $X$ be a space; suppose that $h : X → Z$ is an imbedding of $X$ in
the compact Hausdorff space $Z$. Then there exists a corresponding compactification $Y$
of $X$; it has the property that there is an imbedding $H : Y → Z$ that equals $h$ on $X$.
The compactification $Y$ is uniquely determined up to equivalence.
We call $Y$ the compactification induced by the imbedding $h$.

Proof. Given $h$, let $X_0$ denote the subspace $h(X)$ of $Z$, and let $Y_0$ denote its closure
in $Z$. Then $Y_0$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $\bar{X_0}=Y_0$; therefore, $Y_0$ is a
compactification of $X_0$.

In first part of the proof, they suppose there is a subspace $X_0$ of $h(X)$ which can be compactification.

I wonder how can we explain the existance of $X_0$ which can be compactification.

the definition of compamctification is following

A compactification of a space $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space $Y$ containing
$X$ as a subspace such that $\bar{X}=Y$ .

Comment: The proof assumes $X_0:=h(X)$. $X_0$ is not a proper subspace of $h(X)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X_0$ is **defined** as $h[X]$, the image of $X$ in $Z$. Because $h$ is an embedding $X_0$ is homeomorphic to $X$ via $h$. We then take the closure $Y_0:=\overline{X_0}$ in $Z$ and as $Z$ is compact, $Y_0$ is also compact (being closed in a compact space), and the "copy" of $X$, i.e. $X_0$, is dense in $Y_0$ *by definition*. So really, $Y_0$ is the compactification we're looking for, but Munkres has a restrictive definition of a compactification $Y$ of $X$: $X$ itself must be a subspace of $Y$ (and *not*, as most other topology texts do, a homeomorphic copy of $X$ is a subspace of $Y$, because in that case we'd be done already). So we need to "copy" $Y_0$ and build it "around $X$", as it were, and that's what the rest of the proof does, if you look in Munkres.

$Y_0$ is a "Munkres style" compactification of $X_0$ and $X_0 \simeq X$ via $h$ so we build $Y \simeq Y_0$ around $X$ so that the homeomorphism that achieves that is just $h$ on $X$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I misunderstood the sentence "let $X_0$ denote the subspace h(X) of Z" as "let $X_0$ denote the subspace of h(X) of Z".

Answer (score 0):

$X_0\subset Z$ is defined as $f(X)$, that is
$$
\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}.
$$
This obviously exists. Then we will construct its compactification. To get $Y_0$, we take the closure of $X_0$ (which always exists). Now, by the given properties of $Z$, we know that $Y_0\subset Z$ must be compact. Furthermore, we can check that it satisfies the definition of a compactification of $X_0$ (the fact that it is embedded in a larger topological space $Z$ is irrelevant).

Also, "which can be compactification" is bad grammar. "compactification" is a noun. I assume you meant "which can be compactified".

Comment: More likely: he forgot the article (common mistake) so read "which can be **a** compactification" instead.